# Get Angle Between Two Vectors On A Circle

Tags: c#, math, vector, game-engine, game-physics

I've a P1,P2 and P3 vectors and I need to angle. It has to positive. 
For instance α = 30,  θ=270

[image]

Have can I calculate P1->P2;α or p1->P3;θ ?

Comment: This is a math question, not programming question. Have you tried anything?

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: [How to Find the Angle Between Two Vectors](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors)

Comment: It's too low level for math.stackexchange.com, too.  A simple search would turn up an answer quickly.  So would perusing the first chapter of any book on vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related Wikipedia article: [Dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

By calculating the dot product of the two vectors and then dividing by the product of their magnitudes, you get cos(angle). Using acos, you can then extract the angle.